# Partial loading large amounts of data in JSON format

Tags: database, algorithm, asp.net-web-api, chat, high-availability

I have a task, it is necessary to implement a partial data download. I need to implement something similar as it is realized in the Periscope App.

What at the moment I have:
Implemented data transmission via websockets. All data sent over websockets stored on the server database.
The problem is that the data taken by the server in one minute can be up to 1 MB for 20 minutes of data can accumulate 20 mb!
Then these data should be sent to another client but after a few hours, that is it is not in real time.

I started looking for approximate implementation of this mechanism, but found only a limited download from the server by date range and on the number of entries. I.e:
startDate =  and endDate = , length = 100 and the skip = 10. This solution is not appropriate, since I can send over this period of time (or number) on the 100MB (for example) of data.

I looked how it is implemented at the Periscope App, they run queries:

**First query:**

```
POST https://url/k=<room>/chatapi/v1/history HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: ChatMan/1 (Android) tv.periscope.android/1.6 (1900249)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 230
Host: prod-chatman-ancillary-us-east-1.periscope.tv
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"access_token":"<hidden>","cursor":"","limit":1000,"since":0}
```

*In response, the application receives the first data for a chat.*

```
{cursor:"1473988864446290384",messages:[<largeData>]}
```

And so on packet by packet.

Then the application takes from the data variable "cursor". And makes a second request using the variable "cursor"

```
{"access_token":"<hidden>","cursor":"1473988823917918518","limit":1000,"since":1473988823694000000}
```

As the generated variable "cursor" and "since" I Do not know, maybe you know? 
It is noteworthy that when I do a rewinds in the application I get a different value "since", it is generated in the application. When data is received "cursor" has a different meaning from the data I received immediately after waiting a full load when I went into broadcasting. Hence I assume that for each request, the server creates packages of the messages for each client. 
Kind of like a chat implemented using Pubnub, but I could be wrong.

I hope for the help of experts. Server will highly loaded so I would like most optimal and good decision on the similarity periscope.
I would be glad if you would tell a story of a chat at Periscope can be arranged.

The programming language does not matter.